# How to throw an error when using a property of an object

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I would like JS to throw an error when a object is used that isn't properly instantiated.

I have tried like this already:

```
var person = function () { throw new Error('Person not instantiated!'); };
...
var x = person.age; //should throw an error when person isn't overwritten
```

but it doesn't throw an error like I want it (only if I would type `person();`).

The problem here is that I give the object into numerious methods and don't want to make error handling for all occurrences. Is there a way to throw an error when reading a property of an object?

Comment: Why would that throw an error? You _can_ add arbitrary properties to a function object, and unless you call it the code in the function body never runs.

Comment: I want it to throw an error no matter which property is read. I don't really care about adding new properties but that could be prevented very easily with `seal()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to throw an error when reading a property of an object?*

Yes you can patch the property getter with a function throwing an error

```js
var person = {};
Object.defineProperty(person, 'age', {
  get: function () { throw new Error('Person not instantiated!') }, 
});

var x = person.age;
```

Or you can also replace the object with a `Proxy` that will allow you to override a getter for all properties:

```js
var person = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, name) {
    throw new Error('Person not instantiated!');
  }
});

var x = person.age;
var y = person.name;
```

But all of this is an anti-pattern. Is something that I would suggest against.

Comment: The second one is exactly what I wanted, thanks!